# Proving the complete monotonicity of $f$ given $(−\log f)′$ is completely monotone

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions

A function $f:(0,∞)→[0,∞]$ is said to be completely monotonic if its $n$-th derivative exists and $(−1)^nf^{(n)}(x)≥0$, where $f^{(n)}(x)$ is the $n$-th derivative of $f$.

Prove that if $(−\log f(x))′$ is completely monotonic, then $f(x)$ is also completely monotonic.

There are a few papers that use this without explicitly displaying the proof. It may help to display the function as $g(x)=(−\log f(x))′$ then put $f(x)=\exp(−g(x))$ but I have not yet find the pattern to induct the theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not hard to prove the result but the easy proof needs a detour through absolutely monotonic functions ($g \ge 0$ s.t all its derivatives are also positive/non-negative) since while essentially equivalent to completely monotonic functions by $f(x)=g(-x)$, their closure properties are much easier to state and obvious to prove:

1: Let $g(x)=f(-x)$, $g$ defined on $(-\infty,0)$ and to prove $f$ completely monotonic is equivalent to proving $g$ absolutely monotonic

2: Any positive/non-negative primitive of an absolutely monotonic functions is absolutely monotonic trivially from the definition

3: $(−\log f(y))′=(\log g(x))′, y=-x$, hence by the hypothesis and the above, $\log g(x)+C$ is absolutely monotonic for some $C>0$ since $\log g$ is a primitive of an absolutely monotonic function on $(-\infty,0)$, so in particular it is finite at $-\infty$

4: If $h_1,h_2$ are absolutely monotonic, their composition is also absolutely monotonic wherever defined since positive/non-negative numbers form a cone

5; $e^x$ is absolutely monotonic everywhere hence $g(x)=\frac{e^{\log g(x)+C}}{e^C}$ is absolutely monotonic on $(-\infty,0)$, so by point $1$, $f$ is completely monotonic on $(0, \infty)$

Comment: If $h_1$, $h_2$ are absolutely monotonic, their composition is also absolutely monotonic. then there must be completely monotonic functions $j_1$ and $j_2$ respectively towards $h$ and therefore their multiplication is also completely monotonic. so i can conclude that the multiplication of two completely monotone functions are also completely monotone. this is true right?

Comment: composition of completely monotonic functions is not necessarily completely monotonic - $\frac{1}{x}, \frac{1}{x^2}$ composing to $x^2$ (however the composition of an absolutely monotonic with a completely monotonic one is completely monotonic, so I guess we could go directly above once we figure out signs for the primitive), multiplication is obviously so but that follows directly from Leibniz rule since you have at each derivative order a sum of all positives or all negatives

Comment: im sorry by composition i meant multiplication. regarding to this change does it hold true?

Comment: multiplication - true as noted (directly from definition and Leibniz rule also); composition no

Comment: im sorry i dont follow what you mean by "but that follows directly from Leibniz rule since you have at each derivative order a sum of all positives or all negatives"

Comment: $(fg)^{(n)}=\sum_{0}^{n}{c_m(f^{(m)}g^{(n-m)})}, c_m >0$ but now either $n$ even when the summands derivative orders in $f,g$ respectively are of the same parity so both positive or both negative by complete monotonicty, hence each summand is positive, so total sum positive, or $n$ is odd, when one derivative order is even, one odd, hence one term is positive, one negative, hence all summands are negative!

Comment: i see, thank you for explaining that part. one last thing, for $y=-x$ how do you equivalent $(−\log f(y))'=(\log g(x))'$. Should it not be $(−\log f(y))'=(-\log g(x))'$?

Comment: The chain rule gives the extra minus - it's a bit misleading the way i wrote it true as the first $'$ is with respect to $y$ and the second with respect to $x$, so connecting them is $\frac{dy}{dx}=-1$

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and knowledge, i really appreciate your help on this matter. Especially for enlightening me on the absolute monotonicity. again thank you very much mr/ms conrad

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: excuse me, if i might add one more question. on point 3 of your answer, why does $\log g(x)$ being a primitive of an absolutely monotonic function on $(-\infty, 0)$ ensure that $\log g(x)$ is finite on $(-\infty, 0)$?

Comment: Because h (the derivative) is increasing, non-negative, so h is finite at $-\infty$ (increasing and cannot be minus infinity by positivity) and then $\log g(x)= \int_{-\infty}^{x}h(y)dy + C$, where $C$ is some (possibly negative) constant; in particular $\log g$ may not be non negative, so not absolutely monotonic, but $\log g -C$ is for sure

Answer (score 1):

A non-negative function $f$ is said to be completely monotonic on an interval $I$ if $f$ has derivatives of all orders on $I$ and
\begin{equation*}
0\le(-1)^{n-1}f^{(n-1)}(x)<\infty
\end{equation*}
for all $x\in I$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

A positive function $f$ is said to be logarithmically completely monotonic on an interval $I$ if its logarithm $\ln f$ satisfies
\begin{equation*}
0\le(-1)^n[\ln f(x)]^{(n)}<\infty
\end{equation*}
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ on $I$.

**A logarithmically completely function on an interval $I$ must be also completely monotonic on $I$, but not conversely.**

The following references contain the concepts and conclusions mentioned above.

1. C. Berg, *Integral representation of some functions related to the gamma function*, Mediterr. J. Math. **1** (2004), no. 4, 433--439; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s00009-004-0022-6.
2. Bai-Ni Guo and Feng Qi, *A property of logarithmically absolutely monotonic functions and the logarithmically complete monotonicity of a power-exponential function*, University Politehnica of Bucharest Scientific Bulletin Series A---Applied Mathematics and Physics **72** (2010), no. 2, 21--30.
3. Feng Qi and Chao-Ping Chen, *A complete monotonicity property of the gamma function*, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications **296** (2004), no. 2, 603--607; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2004.04.026.
4. R. L. Schilling, R. Song, and Z. Vondracek, *Bernstein Functions---Theory and Applications*, 2nd ed., de Gruyter Studies in Mathematics **37**, Walter de Gruyter, Berlin, Germany, 2012; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/9783110269338.